# Como puedo actualizar datos de un select input multiple en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo problema (no se como hacer un UPDATE) a la hora de actulizar la ficha del alumno ya que solo me cambia el nombre y imagen del alumno, y lo que quiero hacer es añadir o quitar los cursos en el que esta inscrito desde un select multiple.

Esta es una captura del archivo edit:

http://127.0.0.1/php/edit_student.php?id=2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Alumnos

```
---------------------------------------------
- student_id - student_name - student_image -
---------------------------------------------
-          1 - Ana          - avatar.jpg    -
-          2 - David        - avatar.jpg    -
-          3 - Jasmine      - avatar.jpg    -
---------------------------------------------
```

Tabla Cursos

```
-------------------------------------------
- course_id - course_title - course_image -
-------------------------------------------
-         7 - Photoshop    - image.jpg    -
-         8 - Cinema 4D    - image.jpg    -
-         9 - Idesign      - image.jpg    -
-        10 - Illustrator  - image.jpg    -
-------------------------------------------
```

Tabla Alumnos_Cursos

```
----------------------------------------------
students_courses_id - course_id - student_id - 
----------------------------------------------
-         1         -      7    -       1   
-         2         -      8    -       2   
-         3         -      9    -       2   
-         4         -      10   -       3   
-         5         -      8    -       1   
----------------------------------------------
```

Mi codigo

```
$connect = connect($database);
if(!$connect){
    header ('Location: ' . SITE_URL . '/controller/error.php');
    }
```

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

```
$course_id = $_POST['course_id'];

$student_id = cleardata($_POST['student_id']);
$student_name = cleardata($_POST['student_name']);
$student_image_save = $_POST['student_image_save'];
$student_image = $_FILES['student_image'];

if (empty($student_image['name'])) {
    $student_image = $student_image_save;
} else{
    $student_image_upload = '../' . $items_config['images_folder'] . $_FILES['student_image']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['student_image']['tmp_name'], $student_image_upload);
    $student_image = $_FILES['student_image']['name'];
}
```

$statment = $connect->prepare(
    'UPDATE students SET student_name = :student_name, student_image = :student_image WHERE student_id = :student_id'
    );

$statment->execute(array(

        ':student_name' => $student_name,
        ':student_image' => $student_image,
        ':student_id' => $student_id

        ));

$statment = $connect->prepare( 'UPDATE students_courses SET course_id = :course_id WHERE student_id ='.$student_id) ;
$statment->execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es recibir el contenido del select y tratarlo en tu codigo PHP como un arreglo, es decir algo como lo siguiente:

```html
<form action="edit_student.php" method="post">
  <select name="selectC[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="7" >Photoshop</option>
    <option value="8">Cinema 3D</option>
    <option value="9">iDesign</option>
    <option value="10">Illustrator</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

En tu PHP:

```
<?php
  //primero tendrias que borrar los cursos que actualmente tenia el alumno
  $statment = $connect->prepare('DELETE FROM students_courses WHERE student_id = :student_id');
  $statment->bindParam(':student_id',$student_id);
  //Una vez que ya los borraste, agregarías los cursos que se enviaron.
  $values = $_POST['selectC'];
  foreach ($values as $course_id){
    $statment = $connect->prepare( 'INSERT INTO students_courses (course_id,student_id) VALUES (:course_id,:student_id) ;
    $statment->bindParam(':course_id',$course_id);
    $statment->bindParam(':student_id',$student_id);
    $statment->execute();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hola Esteban, tengo que quitar todo mi codigo y remplazarlo por el tuyo?

Comment: No, el código que te puse es unicamente para realizar el cambio de cursos.

Comment: Me da muchos errores, tengo que cambiar algo en mi codigo anterior ? donde iria tu codigo exactamente al principio o al final ?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Esteban, solo tengo pregunta, que es la funcion de bindParam ? que hace exactamente?

Comment: Un placer, es para indicar cuál va a ser el valor por el que se van a sustituir los comodines que se usan, por ejemplo se indica que :course_id se va a sustituir por el valor de la variable $course_id